# Cluster provisioning failed after adding a secondary certificate

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I deployed a single node Service Fabric test cluster then followed this instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-security-update-certs-azure to add a secondary certificate. After more than an hour the cluster provisioning fails and stays with the unhealty node with code "PendingClusterUpgradeCannotBeInterrupted". 
Here the log.

> "code": "ClusterUpgradeFailed",
>   "message": "Cluster upgrade failed. Reason Code: 'HealthCheck'
>   "description": "Exception occured while creating an object of type FabricDCA.AzureBlobEtwCsvUploader
>   (assembly AzureFileUploader, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35) for creating consumer AzureBlobServiceFabricEtw. Exception occured while creating an object of type FabricDCA.AzureTableQueryableEventUploader (assembly AzureTableUploader, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35) for creating consumer AzureTableServiceFabric EtwQueryable."

Then I deleted and recreated the cluster with primary and secondary certificate and it worked. However if I try to swap the certificates by the portal the cluster hangs with `"ClusterUpgradeFailed"` (no error description given) and drives to `"Cluster provisioning failed"`.

After serveral attempts this is the situation.

- I am not able to add a secondary certificate on an existing cluster
  neither by ARM nor by Add-AzureRmServiceFabricClusterCertificate
  Powershell command.
- Swapping certificates does not work (the only way
  is by the portal).
- The only way to change a certificate is deleting
  and recreating the cluster.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using keystore to add these certificates first and than use it when building the cluster ?

Comment: I loaded both certificates in a key vault before deploying the cluster

Comment: Interesting, I will give it a try on our Dev cluster and share results with you.

Comment: After several attempts I can swap the certificates only if they are in separated key vaults. This contraddicts the documentation linked above that presents an example with the certificates in the same key vault.

Comment: @Daniele, if the documentation is incorrect I suggest you mention it on the doc itself as well. That way the correct doc team can be alerted and make changes as needed.